# How to disable IntelliJ IDEA version control by default?

Tags: intellij-idea

Every single time I create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA it sets its version control system to Subversion. It's kind of annoying to disable it manually every time. How do I disable it for good, so that the default option for version control is "none"?

Comment: Did you try deleting the Subversion Integration plugin?

Comment: This does not happen by default for me, and as a matter of fact, in the default settings I could not find a way to specify a VCS to use... How are you creating the project and what IJ version are you using?

Comment: @JJF No, I might need it in some other projects.

Comment: @Morfic I use the latest 2017.1 version, but the exact same thing happened on previous versions too. That happens every time I create any project -- Maven, SBT, Gradle, even if I just import the project.

Answer (score 3):

There is no setting which disables version control by default for new projects but we can disable the Subversion (or Git or Mercurial or ...) plugin generally.

To do that:

1. Go to ***File/Settings/Plugins***
2. Choose tab ***Installed***
3. Look for the ***Subversion*** plugin, disable it by removing the tick and clicking "Apply":

[image]

---

### Optional:

Disable Git version control:

- untick ***Git Integration*** (this will disable **Github** and ***Google Cloud Tools Core***, ***Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio*** too)

Disable Mercurial version control:

- untick ***Mercurial Integration***

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Maven by chance? There is an issue with VCS detection for maven projects. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115100

Comment: I do use Maven in some projects, yes. But the thing I described just happened when I created an SBT project from scratch.